# Prolog dcg generating all words from language

Tags: prolog, dcg, left-recursion

I'm trying to write some dcg grammar in prolog which will describe language of
`a^nb^n n>=0`
`"",ab,aabb,aaabbb itd`

All what I wrote is

```
s --> slowo.
slowo --> [a],slowo,[b],!.
slowo --> [].
```

And its good as long as all I want to do is just check if word is correct, but how should dcg grammar look in prolog for `?-phrase(s,X)` which will generate all words from my language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're beginning with Prolog, try to avoid the use of `!/0`. You can generally do better without it.

Here for example, your grammar could be written as follows:

```
s --> [].
s --> [a], s, [b].
```

and queried as follows:

```
?- phrase(s, X).
```

Note that prolog clauses are picked from left to right and top to bottom, so a rule written at the top of another one will be prioritized when the backtracking is involved.

Comment: Thanks it works but is it possible to make s deterministic (without backtracking) when its checking the word and it still can generate all words

Comment: you can use `once/1` if needed : `once(phrase(s, ['a', 'b'])).` or go with `phrase((s, {!}), ['a', 'b']).` or some thing of the sort. But learning to tolerate the `;fail` is an interesting way to solve the problem too :p

Comment: how to use fail in dcg ? as its fail/0 not fail/2?

Comment: how do you want to use it? Post a code sample in your question!

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @Mog's answer, let us consider the more general case:

What, if the grammar is so complex, that reordering DCG-rules will not help?  How can we still enumerate all sentences? If the grammar is formulated in such a manner, that it terminates for a fixed length, we get all sentences with

```
?- length(Xs, N), phrase(s, Xs).
```

The goal `length` alone will enumerate all lists in a fair manner.  That is, starting with the shortest `[]` all lists are enumerated:

```
?- length(Xs, N).
   Xs = [], N = 0
;  Xs = [_A], N = 1
;  Xs = [_A,_B], N = 2
;  Xs = [_A,_B,_C], N = 3
;  Xs = [_A,_B,_C,_D], N = 4
;  ... .
```

And now, the length being fixed, the goal `phrase(s, Xs)` will find all answers for that fixed length. As an example, look at Mat's answer to [this grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589417/question-formal-language-in-prolog).

So this is a general method to inspect a grammar's sentences. However - there is a price to pay for this generality! For grammars with finitely many sentences, out method will not terminate:

`:- use_module(`[`library(double_quotes)`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/double_quotes.pl)`).`

`s --> "a"|"b".`

```
?- phrase(s, Xs).
   Xs = "a"
;  Xs = "b".
```

This grammar works out of the box, but together with `length/2` we get now:

```
?- length(Xs, N),phrase(s, Xs).
   Xs = "a", N = 1
;  Xs = "b", N = 1
;  loops.
```

This method is often called [iterative deepening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search), although this term more precisely imposes a bound to the depth of the derivation.  But we are imposing a bound to the actual "output". So iterative deepening is also able to handle left-recursion, whereas `length/2`  works only for grammars that terminate for a fixed input length.

What makes this technique so particularly interesting in Prolog is that it meshes perfectly with Prolog's chronological backtracking mechanism.

Comment: specifying the length of the list passed to phrase/2 is great! I wasn't aware that this could be done. Obviously, this is perfect for generating all lists of a set length!

Answer (score 2):

In SWI Prolog, I could use:

```
s(X, []).
```

or

```
phrase(s, X).
```

(as you suggested) to get all of the strings.  In order for that to produce any answers without a stack overflow, however, I needed to reverse the order of the two rules for `slowo` and remove the cut from the recursive rule.